# Can I build a web app and a destop app in the same Laravel project?

Tags: laravel, cross-platform

I am building an app for different platforms not by using something that create 1 for 2 like Xamarin or Codename One with Java.

Can I use Laravel to build both a web app and a desktop app in the same project?

Comment: Laravel is for web app only.

Comment: yes u can convert your webapp into desktop app

Comment: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop